# Microsoft's bot framework (bot service) creating chat bot

Tags: .net, node.js, service, bots

Do I still need to code the logic of the bot using the Microsoft bot service?
or they have the feature like chatfuel where in you just need to add rules (like a `WYSIWYG` type) to the bot?

Help will greatly be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now we are working on a visual tool that will help users create their bots in a more organic way. I will keep you updated regarding release date and details.

Comment: Thank you Sir, but then will i expect it Sir , cause right now i am on a chat bot project.

Comment: No date yet. Sorry.

Comment: its okay sir , i have decided to write the code from scratch without any third party tools